# How many threads are created in server process when writing a server using C++ CommonAPI?

Tags: c++, ipc

I have written a service using common API (https://docs.projects.genivi.org/ipc.common-api-tools/3.1.3/html/CommonAPICppUserGuide.html). Internally my commonAPI uses Dbus. The service provides *2 methods and 1 selective broadcast*. When I run the service, I can see **7 threads** are created for the service.
I have gone through some part of user guide on commonAPI but could not get the concept behind the number of threads created.
So my queries are:

How to determine number of threads created due to commonAPI? Does it depends on number of clients connected to the service? Does it depends on number of methods, broadcasts in the service interface?

Comment: I have no knowledge about this "common-api" (brilliant name ;)) , but usually such frameworks create pool of threads to be used when needed. And the exact number is their "implementation detail" so it might be reason you cannot find it in documentation. It might be, e.g., related to number of cores in your computer.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I would expect number of cpu cores - 1, because there's the main thread and cpu cores - 1 worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is will ever be interested in this, you can set the number of threads using the num_dispatchers option in the vsomeip.json configuration file.

See here: https://docs.projects.genivi.org/vSomeIP/2.0.1/html/README.html#_configuration_file_structure